# Graph API get users from Azure AD

Tags: c#, json, azure, active-directory

I have users in my Azure AD, i need to get users from AD and put it in C# list with all their properties. Just like here (*users -> 
all users in the organization*): https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#

I found some documentation but i dont understand how to use it properly. In general, result must be C# list, or maybe json file with users and their properties. Can you please give me an example or something?

Documentation:

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUsers
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer is talking about Microsoft Graph API, while https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUsers is talking about Azure AD Graph API. For detailed comparison between them, you could follow [Microsoft Graph or Azure AD Graph](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/).

In general, Microsoft recommends you use Microsoft Graph over Azure AD Graph. I would recommend you use [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) to communicate with Microsoft Graph API.

In order to authenticate for the Microsoft Graph service, firstly you need to register your application to use the Microsoft Graph API. For Azure AD v2.0, use [the app registration portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/), while for Azure AD v1.0, use [portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com).

For Azure AD v2.0, you could follow this [code sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample) for detailed steps. Moreover, you could also leverage [Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) for acquiring the access token for constructing your `GraphServiceClient`.

For Azure AD v1.0, you need to register your app and grant the permissions for your app to access Microsoft Graph API as follows:

[image]

Then, you could leverage [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) for authenticating.
Moreover, for detailed Microsoft Graph user permissions, you could follow [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions). For Delegated permissions vs Application permissions, you could follow [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#delegated-permissions-application-permissions-and-effective-permissions).

Comment: @Bruce Chen, what would be best practice to achieve same in background without any login. i am looking for correct path?

Comment: AFAIK, you may need to set Application permissions for your AAD app and consented by an admin. Then, you may leverage [client credentials grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to deal with service to service calls instead of impersonating a user.