# Microsoft Authentication Library - Get Group Membership

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-msal

We are now using MSAL in our Xamarin/C# app to [authenticate users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58082960/need-to-add-offline-and-touch-id-to-microsoft-authentication-layer), the next step is to determine whether the authenticated user is a member of certain groups in the organization that allow access to certain features of the app.

I grabbed code from StackOverflow for [querying the membership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58091323/how-to-use-microsoft-graph-api-to-get-all-the-groups-for-authorization-in-net-c), it's throwing an exception "Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" but I've asked IT to [add the "groupMembershipClaims" property](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest) to the mCP's Azure manifest and am hopeful that will fix things.

Here are some highlights of the current code:

```
var interactiveRequest = App.PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes);
var authResult = await interactiveRequest.ExecuteAsync();
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
   new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
      (requestMessage) =>
      {
         // Configure the HTTP bearer Authorization Header
         requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
         return (Task.FromResult(0));
      }
      ));
   var groups = await graphClient.Me.MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();
```

I'm assuming I can get that to work, but now I'm reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170029/graph-api-get-users-from-azure-ad) about the differences between Microsoft Graph API and Microsoft AD Graph API and I don't know whether the code I found is the "right" code to use here, or whether there is simpler/better code that I should be using.  Is the code I have there for determining group membership the recommended option?

**EDIT**

IT set "groupMembershipClaims" to "SecurityGroup" and it gives the same exception, so apparently querying membership isn't the same as making membership claims.  But in my case there is one group (role?) that says "this user is allowed to run the app" and another group/role that says "this user has access to the special features" so I don't want the authentication request to just fail if the user isn't a member of that second group/role.

Comment: Yeah you need delegated permissions to read group data from MS Graph API. The membership claims setting just sends group ids in the id token. Unless the user has too many groups. In that case it won't contain any.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the groups the user belongs to, you can analyze the id_token. The id_token has one claim "groups", it will tell you the id of groups the user belongs to. For example

1. Configure app manifest

Please update the `groupMembershipClaims` value as `All`.
[image]

2. get Id token

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e        // Your registered Application ID
&response_type=id_token%20code
&redirect_uri=      // Your registered redirect URI, URL encoded
&response_mode=form_post                             // 'form_post' or 'fragment'
&scope=openid%20                                      // Include both 'openid' and scopes that your app needs  
offline_access%20                                         
https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read
&state=12345                                          // Any value, provided by your app
&nonce=678910                                         // Any value, provided by your app
```

3. Alayse id token vai jwt.io
   [image]

Comment: @betty Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concern, could you please accept the answer? It may help more people.